# Android background at bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to implement a background of `LinearLayout`. The background of `LinearLayout`
containing image repeat with a light border at the bottom of the `LinearLayout`. I achieved image repeat at the background of the `LinearLayout` but unable to add border **ONLY** at the bottom of the `LinearLayout`. I tried many solution but couldn't succeeded.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  



     <item android:drawable="@drawable/bitmaprepeat" />
    <item  android:bottom="1px"  android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape> 
            <solid/>
           <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#dddddd" />  

        </shape>
    </item>
   </layer-list>
```

where bitmaprepeat is a drawable where I am repeating image in the background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display bottom border you need to add padding from bottom for last item like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ff0000"/>
        </shape>
    </item><!-- Lower Drawable -->

    <item android:bottom="10px">
         <shape>
            <solid android:color="#00ff00"/>
        </shape>
    </item><!-- Upper Drawable, Use your drawable here like android:drawable="@drawable/img" in <item> tag-->

</layer-list>
```

You can see output on attached image.
[image]

Comment: thanks Amol. I alwys confuse about this. can you tell me or refer me any good tutorial where I can see how this xml work to define item and how they work

Comment: @Me Malik: For more detail information about layer-list please go through this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList